# json and php If, else statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

This php code generates a table with some information like: temperature, water health, ph level and other things ...

```
if (count($auxGateway->getMaquina()) > 0)
{
    foreach($auxGateway->getMaquina() as $maq)
    {
        echo '<div class="cont-maq-uni">';//Cria a div para cada maquina
        echo '  <table class="maq">';//Cria uma tabela
        echo '      <tr>';
        echo '          <td colspan="2">';
        echo '              <h2 class="maq-head">'.$maq->getNome().'</h2>';
        echo '          </td>';
        echo '      </tr>';
        foreach($maq->getVariavel() as $var)
        {
            echo '  <tr class="maq">';
            echo '      <td class="maq">';
            echo '          <p class="n_font maq">'.$var->getNome().'</p>';
            echo '      </td>';
            echo '      <td class="maq">';
            echo '          <p class="n_font maq">'.(floatval($var->getValor()) * floatval($var->getMultiplicador()) + floatval($var->getSomador())).' '.$var->getUnidadeValor().'</p>';
            echo '      </td>';
            echo '  </tr>';
        }
        echo '  </table>';
        echo '</div>'; 
    }
}
```

so I need to create a code to show some images if that information is bigger or less. For example: if 'temperature' <30 then it will show the image (notgood.jpeg). The problem is: how do I name these values since they are inside the MYSQL database? How will I name each row in the table?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Which values where in the database? The temperature or the filename of the image?Please describe your question and problem more particularly .

Comment: @ToyRobotic The temperature and another informations are in the database. They are update by an ip (gateway).

Comment: Why didn't you do something like this? 

if( $var->getTemperature() > maxValue) ....
 // your information image
else
// another information image
?

Sorry, but I didn't get your problem

Comment: The `if (count($auxGateway->getMaquina()) > 0) {` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if..else.. or ternary operators

```
echo '<img src="' . ($var->getTemperature() < 30 ? 'notgood.jpeg' : 'good.jpeg') . '">' # using ternary operators;
```

This will give, if $var->getTemperature() < 30 `<img src="notgood.jpeg">`
else `<img src="good.jpeg">`